# Javascript constructor functions in "subclass", correct notation?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype

I am trying to come to grips with javascript inheritance. My example code starts like this:

```
var example = example || {};
example.Classes = {};

(function() {
    var example = example || {};
    example.Classes = {};

    var privateVar = 25;
    function Superclass() {
        this.x = privateVar;
    }
    Superclass.prototype = {
        move: function(x){
            this.x += x;
            console.log("Superclass move",this.x);
        },
        dance: function(x){
            this.x += x*2;
        }
    };

    function Subclass() {
        Superclass.apply(this, arguments);
        this.y = 0;
    };
    Subclass.prototype = Object.create(Superclass.prototype);
    Subclass.prototype.constructor = Subclass;
```

This is the successful continuation:

```
    Subclass.prototype.dance = function(x, y) {
      this.x -= (x + privateVar);
      this.y -= y;
      console.log("Subclass dance", this.x, this.y)
    };
    example.Classes.Superclass = Superclass;
    example.Classes.Subclass = Subclass;
    window.example.Classes = example.Classes;
}());

var success = new example.Classes.Subclass();
success.dance(5,4);
success.move(6);
```

console output: Subclass dance -5 -4  
console output: Superclass move 1

And now the continuation that fails - what is wrong here? Why can't I use this way of writing the subclass constructor functions?

```
    Subclass.prototype = {
        dance: function(x, y) {
            this.x -= (x + privateVar);
            this.y -= y;
            console.log("Subclass dance", this.x, this.y)
        }
    };

    example.Classes.Superclass = Superclass;
    example.Classes.Subclass = Subclass;
    window.example.Classes = example.Classes;
}());

var failure = new example.Classes.Subclass();
failure.dance(5,4);
failure.move(6);
```

console output: Subclass dance -5 -4
console output: ERROR: failure.move is not a function

Comment: I suggest giving a read to [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). You shouldn't need all of the `Classes`/`Subclass`/`Superclass` stuff...

Comment: So my question boils down to what is the difference between  `Subclass.prototype.dance = function(x, y){};`  and
`Subclass.prototype = {dance:function(){}};` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't I use this way of writing the subclass constructor functions?

Because you're blowing away the object that used to be on the `Subclass.prototype` property (the one from `Object.create(Superclass.prototype)`) and *replacing* it with an object whose prototype is `Object.prototype` with just one property, `dance`.

Once you've created the `Subclass.prototype` object, you always want to *augment it* as you did originally:

```
Subclass.prototype.dance = /*...*/;
```

not *replace* it:

```
// Not this
Subclass.prototype = { dance: /*...*/ };
```

ES2015 added a handy function for merging properties from one object (or a series of them) into a target object: [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). It can be polyfilled (mostly) for older JavaScript engines. Using that, you could do:

```
Object.assign(Subclass.prototype, {
    dance: function dance() { /* ... */ },
    skip:  function skip()  { /* ... */ },
    jump:  function jump()  { /* ... */ }
});
```

---

**Having said that,** here in 2016, I would suggest using the `class` feature added in ES2015 (transpiling if necessary for older JavaScript engines):

```
class Superclass {
    constructor() {
        //...
    }

    method() {
        // ...
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // ...
    }

    anotherMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful!